# Fill null values with linear interpolation using DuckDB

Tags: sql, duckdb

I am trying to fill null values in a numeric table using duckdb.

Let's consider the simple table `df`:

| x | y |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 2.0 |
| 1 | NULL |
| 3 | NULL |
| 5 | 7.0 |
| 6 | 4.0 |
| 8 | 5.0 |
| 9 | NULL |

that you can create with

```sql
CREATE TABLE df (x NUMERIC, y NUMERIC)
INSERT INTO df VALUES (0, 2), (1, NULL), (3, NULL), (5, 7), (6, 4), (8, 5), (9, NULL)
```

then i would like to create a SELECT statement to retrieve:

| x | y |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 2.0 |
| 1 | 3.0 |
| 3 | 5.0 |
| 5 | 7.0 |
| 6 | 4.0 |
| 8 | 5.0 |
| 9 | NULL |

I think that a correlated subquery which finds the following and previous non-null values and then computes the interpolation should work:

```sql
SELECT
    x,
    COALESCE(
        y,
        (
            SELECT 
                prev.y + ( (next.y - prev.y) * (parent.x - prev.x) / (next.x - prev.x) )
            FROM
                ( SELECT x, y FROM df WHERE x <= parent.x and y is not null ORDER BY x DESC LIMIT 1 ) AS prev
            CROSS JOIN
                ( SELECT x, y FROM df WHERE x >= parent.x and y is not null ORDER BY x ASC LIMIT 1 ) AS next
        )
    ) AS y
FROM
    df parent
```

But duckdb is complaining with

```
INTERNAL Error: Failed to bind column reference "limit_rownum" [30.0] (bindings: [8.0 8.1 8.2 28.0])
```

EDIT: Adjusted the example to ensure that `x` and `y` columns are both taken into account for interpolating the gaps.

Comment: Are LEAD and LAG available?

Comment: Postgresql handles your query; https://dbfiddle.uk/3anzk06a

Comment: @jarlh Yes, they are available.

Comment: with the updated sample, postgres runs your query https://dbfiddle.uk/QS35UKJo and matched expected results

Comment: btw: the duckdb error may due to a bug. see https://github.com/duckdb/duckdb/issues/9720

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can bypass the error message by adopting row_number() as proposed in this [duckdb bug reference](https://github.com/duckdb/duckdb/issues/9720). nb: The fiddle below uses postgres as I'm unable to test in duckdb:

```
CREATE TABLE df (x NUMERIC(3,1), y NUMERIC(3,1));

INSERT INTO df VALUES (0, 2), (1, NULL), (3, NULL), (5, 7), (6, 4), (8, 5), (9, NULL)

SELECT
    x,
    COALESCE(
        y,
        (
            SELECT 
                prev.y + ( (next.y - prev.y) * (parent.x - prev.x) / (next.x - prev.x) )
            FROM
                ( SELECT x, y, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY x DESC) as rn FROM df WHERE x <= parent.x and y is not null ) AS prev
            CROSS JOIN
                ( SELECT x, y, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY x ASC) as rn FROM df WHERE x >= parent.x and y is not null ) AS next
            WHERE
                prev.rn = next.rn
        )
    ) AS y
FROM
    df parent
```

| x | y |
| --- | --- |
| 0.0 | 2.0 |
| 1.0 | 3.00000000000000000000 |
| 3.0 | 5.0000000000000000 |
| 5.0 | 7.0 |
| 6.0 | 4.0 |
| 8.0 | 5.0 |
| 9.0 | *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/77YE2dPQ)

Comment: Wow, thanks Adrian! That, indeed does work, as you can test directly in your browser using their wasm implementation: https://shell.duckdb.org/ . Kudos for finding that bug report.

Comment: Do you have an explanation what the row number windowing function does here? And what the `WHERE prev.rn = next.nr` is for in particular?

Comment: Your original query relies on each correlated query returning one "previous" and one "next" rows. These are inherently related by the subquery structure. Given the bug it isn't possible to use the same approach, so each row_number() grants an integer reference to each row found (which can be more than one), in ascending, or descending order. To achieve the equivalent of the previous inherent relationship we now need to instruct that the rn of the ascending should equal the rn of the descending  and hence that former relationship is re-established.

Comment: Ok, i dug a bit deeper, by playing with the subquery itself. It actually does not work reliably in its current form because the subquery can have multiple solutions, since the second previous with the second next non-null y also satisfies the `prev.rn = next.rn` criteria.

Comment: ie. for an example like `INSERT INTO df VALUES (-1, 1), (0, 2), (1, NULL), (3, NULL), (5, 7), (6, 4), (8, 5), (9, NULL)`, it breaks, unless we change `prev.rn = next.rn` to `prev.rn = 1 and next.rn = 1` or add a `LIMIT 1`. ie. see https://dbfiddle.uk/IjMqsCVw